# Django: Why is create_user not working? (Custom BaseUserManager)

Tags: python, django, customization

I am working on a Django project, where I have a custom AbstractBaseUser and a custom BaseUserManager. Logically I created those pretty early and since they were doing what they are supposed to, I went on in the project.
Now I am at a point, where I want to add the atribute userTag to the custom User and I want to call the function  generate_userTag, when an user is created (same for superuser). So I added the fuction to the create_user I already had "working"; at least I thought it would. Turns out, no changes I make in the create_user function are getting applyed or have any impact on the project. Its like the fuction never gets called. I added an ValueError that should raise erytime the function is getting called, but when I register a new user from the testsite, there is no error and the user gets created without the userTag.

Now the weird part: I tested to create a superuser and to my surprise it was working flawlessly. The superuser gets created, with the userTag. Everything fine.

So my question: What could cause Django to not call the custom create_user, when creating a user, but call the custom create_superuser, when creating a superuser?

thanks for helping

---

account/models.py

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            userTag=generate_userTag(username),         
        )       

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

---

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    userTag                 = models.CharField(max_length=35, default="#00000")    
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_image           = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath, null=True, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
    hide_email              = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

---

account/views.py

```
def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated: 
        return HttpResponse("You are already authenticated as " + str(user.username))

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email').lower()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            destination = kwargs.get("next")
            if destination:
                return redirect(destination)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

---

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'
```

Comment: How do you create the superuser - with `./manage.py createsuperuser`? And how do you create the user? Can you provide the code/commands for both?

Comment: For superuser I use ./manage.py createsuperuser. For user I use the registration_view function (added above). I basically copyed that part so im not 100% sure what is happening there. Is the form.save() creating the new user?

Comment: You have not provided the import, so I'm not sure which `RegistrationForm` you are using. As this is Python, you can simply look into the code of it to see what it is doing. A well configured IDE such (e.g. VisualStudioCode or PyCharm) will easily help you with that by allowing you to click on the Reference and opening the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing

```
form.save()
```

with

```
account = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=raw_password)
```

in the registration view.

Im still not sure what the problem was, so if sb can explain, id appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a user with forms, it avoids the model manager. It calls `model_instance.save()` method instead of `model.objects.create_user()`. So you can add logic in model's **save()** method.

Maybe something like this could do the work:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some logic, for example:
        if self._state.adding and self.username:
            self.userTag=generate_userTag(self.username)
        # then super
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**But notice:** the method **user_create()** calls **save()** at the end, so your logic can work twice, we need to anticipate it in advance.

---

I believe there is a better solution for this problem. Nevertheless, it helped me in my project.